# Changing author name in Sign Key -BB10

Tags: blackberry-10

I need to change the author name so is it possible if I change it in MANIFEST.MF file will it update the product in appworld?

If I sign with the a different sign key and change the package id of previous MANIFEST.MF I had so will that update the build I have in appworld?

Please tell me which of the above process would help me update the product with a different author name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the author in your IDE. Go to Windows | Preferences | BlackBerry | Signing and click Create Certificate giving the new Author name. This should allow you to upload your app using the same keys to BlackBerry World.

[image]

Make sure you back up your keys first, just in case anything goes wrong!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but if you change any of those details you will need to upload as a new application, or BlackBerry World will reject it. If I were you I would 
[Contact BlackBerry World Vendor Support](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8109), they will help you out. They can reset those details